# UIImagePickerController ,Get the event of Take Photo Button?

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I want to be able to show a `cameraOverlayView` on `UIImagePickerController` only when the user is taking the photo. That means that it has to be hidden after a photo has been taken and it has to be shown again if the Retake button has been tapped. Is there a way to handle those events?

Comment: ImagePicker delegates bruh.

Comment: ImagePicker delegates can only  get the finsih state,it not i want

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show a customView like an overlay then use `UIImagePickerController` property `cameraOverlayView` and assign your custom view to this property.

```
picker.cameraOverlayView = overlay;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and I solved it by adding two observers when creating the `UIImagePickerController`.

One to remove the overlay when a photo is taken:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name("_UIImagePickerControllerUserDidCaptureItem"), object: nil, queue: nil) { _ in
    picker.cameraOverlayView = nil
}
```

and one for the case the user taps on "Retake":

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name("_UIImagePickerControllerUserDidRejectItem"), object: nil, queue: nil) { _ in
    picker.cameraOverlayView = yourOverlayView
}
```